How can I prove $\operatorname{dim null}(ST)$ is less than or equal to $\operatorname{dim null}S + \operatorname{dim null}T$?
Problem from linear algebra done right.
We are given that $U$ and $V$ are finite-dimensional and T $\in$ $\mathcal{L} (U,V)$ and $S \in \mathcal{L} (V,W)$. We want to show
$$\operatorname{dim null}(ST) \leq \operatorname{dim null} T + \operatorname{dim null} S.$$
I tried using the fundamental theorem of linear maps but wasn't able to get much process, so instead I am using bases to solve the problem.
This is my work so far:
If $u \in \operatorname{null} T$, then $(ST)u = S(Tu) = S(0) = 0$ which implies that $u \in \operatorname{null} ST$. Hence, $\operatorname{null} T$ is a subspace of $\operatorname{null} ST$.
Let $u_1,\ldots,u_n$ be a basis for $\operatorname{null} T$. Extend the list to a basis $u_1,\ldots,u_n, v_1, \ldots, v_m$ of $\operatorname{null}(ST)$. So,
$$\operatorname{dim null} (ST) = n + m.$$
If I want to complete my proof, I only need to show that $m \leq \operatorname{dim null} S $.
Now, notice that if $u \in \operatorname{null} ST$, then $u = b_1 u_1 +\ldots+ b_n u_n + a_1 v_1 + \ldots + a_m u_m$ where the $a$'s and $b$'s are constants. We also know that $Tu \in \operatorname{null} S$. Then,
$Tu = a_1Tv_1 + \ldots + a_mTv_m$ where the other $u$'s got deleted since they were in $\operatorname{null} T$.
But here is where I am not sure where to go. I don't know if this method actually will lead me anywhere or if it's just easier to use the linear map theorem.

Or you need to show that $m\leq\operatorname{dim null} S$?

I don't know how to make your attempt to work, but here is a (sketch of a) solution.
Let $R:\mathrm{null}(ST)\to V$ be the restriction of $T$ to $\mathrm{null}(ST)$, that is
$$
Ru = Tu, \quad u\in \mathrm{null}(ST).
$$
First prove that the image of $R$ is contained in the null space of $S$, that is
$$
\mathrm{img}(R)\subseteq \mathrm{null}(S),
$$
where (I write this just for make the notation clear)
$$
\mathrm{img}(R) = \{Rx \; | \; x\in \mathrm{null}(ST)\}.
$$
Now, you can easily verify that $\mathrm{null}(R) = \mathrm{null}(T)$ (here you must use that $\mathrm{null}(T)\subseteq \mathrm{null}(ST)$). Then by the rank-nullity theorem we have that (since the domain of $R$ is $\mathrm{null}(ST)$,
$$
\dim\mathrm{null}(ST) = \dim\mathrm{null}(R) + \dim\mathrm{img}(R)\leq \dim\mathrm{null}(T) + \dim\mathrm{null}(S).
$$

Thanks, one question I still have is: why would this proof fail if V was not finite-dimensional? I know why U must be finite-dimensional since we need null(ST) to be finite dimensional. But why is V being finite-dimensional a requirement?

Your approach will work.
Note that $\ker T \subset \ker ST$. Let $u_1,...,u_n$ be a basis for $\ker T$, extend with $v_1,...v_m$ to form a basis for $\ker ST$.
The relevant fact is that $Tv_1,...,Tv_m$ are linearly independent and $STv_k = 0$ for all $k$, so $\operatorname{sp} \{ T v_k \} \subset \ker S$ and hence $ m \le \dim \ker S$.
Then $\dim \ker ST = n+m \le \dim \ker T + \dim \ker S$.
Elaboration:
Suppose $\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i T v_i = 0$, then $\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i v_i \in \ker T$ and so $\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i v_i = \sum_{j=1}^n \beta_j u_j$ from which we get $\alpha_i = 0, \beta_j = 0$. Hence the $T v_i$ are linearly independent.

I did think of this, but how can you tell that $Tv_1, ... , Tv_m$ is linearly independant?

@Sushi I added an elaboration.

You worked with basis. Without considering basis or elements:
$$\begin{align}\operatorname{dim null}(ST)&=\dim (ST)^{-1}(0)\\
&=\dim T^{-1}(S^{-1}(0))\\
&=\dim T^{-1}(\operatorname{Im} T\cap \operatorname{null}S)\\
&=\dim T^{-1}(W)\\
&=\dim T^{-1}(0)+\dim W
\end{align}$$
where $\dim( W)\leq\operatorname{dim null}S$
Therefore,
$$\operatorname{dim null}(ST)
\leq \operatorname{dim null} T + \operatorname{dim null} S.$$
